# PLS-00049: bad bind variable Triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to make this trigger work. What it does is, this will execute before deleting data from a table and its affiliated table, then insert that deleted data into 2 tables (which I named into tb1_arch and tb2_arch). I've been searching possible fixes in google but I really have no idea how to make this work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE DELETE ON tb1 FOR EACH ROW
FETCH
INSERT INTO tb1_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.tb1Date,:old.CustomerName);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data archived.');
END;
```

the trigger was created above. but when I added this line

```
INSERT INTO tb2_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.ItemNum, :old.Pieces);
```

after `INSERT INTO tb1_arch VALUES`, it gives me an error

"Error at line 5: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.PIECES'"

Any help would be appreciated!

*EDIT: as Mr. Vijayakumar suggested, I did the following:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
    BEFORE DELETE ON tb1 
    REFERENCING OLD AS old FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO tb1_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.tb1Date,:old.CustomerName);
    INSERT INTO tb2_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.ItemNum, :old.Pieces);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data archived.');
    END
```

However, I'm still having the same error.

*EDIT: removed FETCH, I'm still encountering the same problem*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE DELETE ON tb1 FOR EACH ROW

INSERT INTO tb1_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.tb1Date,:old.CustomerName);
INSERT INTO tb2_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.ItemNum, :old.Pieces);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data archived.');
END;
```

The table are as follows:
tb1:

```
create table tb1 (
    OrderNum integer NOT NULL primary key,
    tb1Date date NOT NULL,
    CustomerName varchar2(50) NOT NULL,

--constraints
    CONSTRAINT tb1_uc unique (CustomerName)
);
```

tb2

```
create table tb2 (
    OrderNum integer NOT NULL,
    ItemNum integer NOT NULL,
    Pieces integer NOT NULL,

--constraints
    CONSTRAINT tb2_fk foreign key (OrderNum) references tb1(OrderNum),
);
```

Comment: You should add reference `REFERENCING OLD AS OLD`

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for replying! I did the following
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE DELETE ON tb_1 
REFERENCING OLD AS old FOR EACH ROW
However, I'm still having the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `FETCH` should be causing this, replace it by `BEGIN`, which is the right syntax,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE DELETE ON tb1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tb1 VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.Date,:old.CustomerName);
INSERT INTO tb2_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.ItemNum, :old.Pieces);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data archived.');
END;
```

> **EDIT:** The column name you refer using `OLD` might be invalid, which is the reason for this error.

Trigger will be applicable for only **ONE** Table's `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` event. Though, you can refer multiple tables in the body.

But `OLD` and `NEW` will be always referring the table you mentioned in DDL like `DELETE ON tb1`.

The below modified code will help you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE DELETE ON tb1 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_ItemNum tb2.ItemNum%TYPE;
   v_Pieces tb2.Pieces%TYPE;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tb1_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, :old.Date,:old.CustomerName);

   /* Select the values for this item from table 2 */
   SELECT ItemNum,Pieces
    INTO v_ItemNum,v_Pieces
   FROM tb2
    WHERE OrderNum = :old.OrderNum;

   /* Insert the selected values in the table2's archive version */
   INSERT INTO tb2_arch VALUES (:old.OrderNum, v_ItemNum, v_Pieces);

   /* Delete the entry */
   DELETE from tb2 WHERE OrderNum = :old.OrderNum;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data archived.');
END;
```

Alternatively, you can have another trigger `for delete on table2` and archive the data there.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying to my post! I did as you told, and I'm still having the same problem. And yes, it was my mistake the FETCH shouldn't be there. I first tried tackling the problem with a cursor but it didn't work.

Comment: Otherwise, the column name `Pieces` should be invalid. Can you describe the table `tb_1` ?

Comment: i'll just add it at the post so you can read it more easily haha

Comment: Ok, so the column `pieces` does not exists? And you refer it using `OLD` ?

Comment: it doesn't exist on tb1. The column "Pieces" exists in tb2. And I had a typo on my code, it should be tb1 not tb_1 (still the same error).

Comment: @EssirNaya the updated answer will give you more insight on your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT WORKED! Thank you very much for your help! And I understand what error that I've kept on doing. Thank you for explaining it thoroughly!